# Painting Table with Session Values

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, background-color

Let's say I have a dynamically-created table that is filled with data from a MySQL db from a `SELECT` sentence.

Now, I need to access a variable that is defined inside of an `if` clause inside of the table, from the outside. For making that, I'm using some `$_SESSION` values, but when I try to apply this coloring to the entire row, it colors up all the table instead of a single row in which the session value is stored. I'm guessing that I need to save also the `$RowCt` value, but dunno how.

I've been with this problem for quite a while, and looks like I'm a little bit blinded after looking at this code continuously. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
<?php include("../includes/header.php")?>
<div class="content" align="center">

<?php
    function SQLResultTable($Query)
    {
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "...", "...") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("...") or die('Could not select database');
        $Table = "";

        $Table.= "<table border='0' align='center'>";

        $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
        if(mysql_error())
        {
            $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
        }
        else
        {
            //Header Row with Field Names
            $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #D00000; float:center; font-size:14px; color: #FFFFFF;\" align='center'>";
            for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
            {    
                if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a1") { $Table.= "<th>a1</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a2") { $Table.= "<th>a2</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a3") { $Table.= "<th>a3</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a4") { $Table.= "<th>a4</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a5") { $Table.= "<th>a5</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a6") { $Table.= "<th>a6</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a7") { $Table.= "<th>a7</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a8") { $Table.= "<th>a8</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a9") { $Table.= "<th>a9</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a10") { $Table.= "<th>a10</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a11") { $Table.= "<th>a11</th>"; 
                } else if ((mysql_field_name($Result, $i))=="a12") { $Table.= "<th>a12</th>"; 
                } else { $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; }
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";

            $RowCt = 0;

            while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
            {
                $timezone = new DateTimeZone( "Europe/London" );
                $date = new DateTime();
                $date->setTimezone( $timezone );
                $now = $date->format( 'H:i' );

                if (!isset($_SESSION['b2'])) {
                    $Table.="<tr style='background-color:red;'>";
                } else if (!isset($_SESSION['b1'])) {
                    $Table.="<tr style='background-color:yellow;'>";
                } else {
                    $Table.="<tr style='background-color:white;'>";
                }

                foreach($Row as $field => $value) {
                    if ($field == 'b1') {
                        if ($value > $now) {
                            $_SESSION['b1'] = $b1;
                            $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";
                        } else {
                            $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";
                        }
                    } else if ($field == 'b2') {
                        if ($value > $now) {
                            $_SESSION['b2'] = $b2;
                            $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";
                        } else {
                            $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";
                    }
                }
                $Table.= "</tr>";
            }
            $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size:10px; color: #000000;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'><br />Query returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " result(s).</td></tr>";
        }
        $Table.= "</table>";
        return $Table;
    }
?>

<?php
    echo "<div align='center'><u><strong><a href='index.php'>Query Results</a></strong></u></div>";
    echo SQLResultTable("SELECT a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12 FROM test_db ORDER BY a6"); 
?>
</div>
```

Now, the `$now` value returns the actual hour, i.e. 08:30; and `$value` on fields `b1` and `b2` returns a similar value on the same format that is stored from a previous form.

The deal is this: When it's late (value on field b1 is greater than now), it colors up the row on yellow. If it's very late (value on field b2 is greater than now), it colors up the row on red. Otherwise, the row is on a white background-color.

With the code above, it colors up the entire table. And can't find how to undo this so it colors *just* the row on which the session value is stored, aka where its late or very late.

Any help is appreciated, ask if you need any more data.

Comment: Not answering your initial question, but please try to cleanup the code first. It is readable, but there alot of redundancies. P.e. the `foreach`-loop has multiple conditions which all result to the same comclusion (`Table.= "<td style...`). Just put commands into a condition which are really dependand on the condition. If it doesn't depend on it, don't put it there. Just moving your multiple `$Table`-commands onto the beginning of the `foreach`-loop saves you alot of lines of code. And back to your question...it seems to be more of a CSS problem, not php related. Pls focus on this instead.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll try to simplify it, even thought it's not my original code. More onto the original problem, I don't think that it's *just* a css problem, that's why I've posted it this way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to be pedantic, but there are probably easier and less headache-inducing ways to write this! But in short, I'd say that your code is almost there. Is your table showing up in one colour that depends on the time of day? I'd say it has something to do with your session variables only being ***set***, and never ***unset***...

Would something like this suffice:

```
...
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
{
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone( "Europe/London" );
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone( $timezone );
    $now = $date->format( 'H:i' );

    foreach($Row as $field => $value) {
        if ($field == 'b1') {
            if ($value > $now) {
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:YELLOW;' align='center'>$value</td>";
            } else {
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:WHITE;' align='center'>$value</td>";
            }
        } else if ($field == 'b2') {
            if ($value > $now) {
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:RED;' align='center'>$value</td>";
            } else {
                $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:WHITE;' align='center'>$value</td>";
            }
        } else {
            $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px; background-color:WHITE;' align='center'>$value</td>";
        }
    }
    $Table.= "</tr>";
}
...
```

Sorry if I got the colours mixed up! ;) Hope this helps point you on the right track!

***EDIT:***

Check the commented PHP code below for a solution to switching colours every 3 rows (hope I got it right - wrote it really fast!)

```
...

// so this is my understanding of what I think this code must do
// based on what your original code looks like and what your original
// question was highlighting...

// based on how you're calling the rows and checking the fields for
// values 'b1' and 'b2', I'm making an assumption here that the fields
// 'b1' and 'b2' will always both exist in every row you parse. Maybe you
// shouldn't be checking the '$field' variable for equivalence to 'b1'
// or 'b2', but rather the '$value' variable? Regardless, I'm throwing down
// this code for the '$RowCt' question you had, it will alternate between the
// 3 colours...I hope it helps...

$RowCt = 0;
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
{
    // get the time, that's all working ok...
    $timezone = new DateTimeZone( "Europe/London" );
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone( $timezone );
    $now = $date->format( 'H:i' );

    // increase the counter, work out the colour...
    $RowCt++;

    $background_color = 'white';
    if ($RowCt % 3 == 1)
        $background_color = 'red';
    if ($RowCt % 3 == 2)
        $background_color = 'yellow';

    $Table.="<tr style='background-color:". $background_color .";'>";

    foreach($Row as $field => $value)
        $Table.= "<td style='font-size:14px;' align='center'>$value</td>";

    $Table.= "</tr>";
}

...
```

Comment: Got that through while I was checking it down; so thanks for it. However, that only paints those fields (with the correct colors, once that I change that mixed up ;P) instead of the entire row. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: And btw, about the question you posted. Thought I had that clearly on the original question, but it's willing to show up the entire row on a defined color (yellow/red/white) when a field from that row is a greater value than the actual time.

Comment: Haha no problem! Well, seeing as it wasn't your code, maybe re-writing it might help not only simplifying it but also fixing the problem. If you're bent on using the original code, I might try unsetting the other session variables while setting a specific one, otherwise try work the row background colour switching into my code above :)

Comment: Yup, working on it. Cleared up the sessions, and no luck by now; gone back to the first original piece of code (with your addition), and I think that I should save the `$RowCt` value for the row in which the condition is fulfilled. Any idea how? For example, posting `if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;"; else $Style = "background-color: #0099CC;";` would return on a row-color-alternation. How could that be done for modifying the color row on a variable definition?

Comment: Would a couple of `if {} else if {} else {}` statements not do the trick?

Comment: Tried that earlier, but doesn't looks to work, unfortunately. It just paints the entire table with the first color it picks. Maybe I'm not coding it right? Could you try a sample?

Comment: No problem Alex, and I hope my sample in my edit above helps, 'cos I'm starting to get the feeling you're really new to PHP and need the assist! Short of actually taking time to write it for you completely, I'm not sure what else I could do! :)

Comment: Many thanks, Chris. Will give it a try tomorrow. I'm not actually new on PHP, but I'm more used to work with this sort of coding object-oriented, on other languages that are not from a markup side :) Even thought, as I see, looks like that modified sample that you wrote alternates colors instead of setting up a specific color when a `$field` value is greater than `$now`. Anyway, tomorrow I'll think on rewriting this. +1 for the effort :)

Comment: Tried it and works like a charm. However, that wasn't what I meant. Let me explain: Your sample alternates the colors (red-yellow-white), but I would need to change the row's color to yellow or red (being white the default color) when a value inside of the foreach loop is defined (and it's defined once that that value is greater than `$now`). Hope that you understand what I mean, and don't worry if you don't have the time for it; i'll keep on trying myself. :)

Comment: So it sounds like you're looking to loop through the data before you're setting the colour of the row? That shouldn't be too difficult - just build the `td` data first while checking for the `$now` value, then build the `tr` data around it after you figured out what colour it needs to be :)